# What is the name of this fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I have attached a photo. I know the Nepali name for this fruit but not its common name in English and its scientific names. In Nepal we call it as 'lahare Aanp' (meaning Climber Mango). This fruit is a climber type like cucumber.

Does anybody know its common name in English and its scientific name?

[image: Fruits to be identified]

Comment: Note that you can easily find the answer by using Google's image search feature. It returns a partially completed version of this drawing, https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/20837253_1095238210612152_3434464044126306304_n.jpg , which is labeled "Coloured Pencil Passionfruit wip".

Answer (score 33):

This is a [passionfruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora_edulis). It comes from a plant whose scientific name is *Passiflora edulis*.

[image]

It's indeed a climber, as you can see:

[image]

Finally, a curiosity about the name *passion fruit*. The fruit is called *passion fruit* because the flower is called *passion flower*. This is the flower:

[image]

But why it is called *passion* flower? *Passion* here has nothing to do with *sexual love* or *desire*, the common meaning of "passion", but with the suffering of Jesus.

Some say that it's because the flower resembles (?) the crown of thorns placed in Jesus' head. Other say that it symbolises Jesus' wounds. In fact, in portuguese we call it *"flor das cinco chagas"*, or flower of the five wounds.

EDIT: thanks to [@AlanBoyd's comment](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65069/what-is-the-name-of-this-fruit#comment117522_65070), you can see that its connections with Christianity are way more complex: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passiflora#Etymology_and_names

---

**Post Scriptum** (not related to the question): this plant is native to Brazil, and I had a couple of specimens in my yard. One of the most interesting things about passionfruits in Brazil is that it attracts an insect that we call *"percevejo do maracujá"*, or *passionfruit bug* in a very free translation. Its scientific name is *Diactor bilineatus*, and it's one of the most beautiful insects to me. I loved to see them feeding on my passionfruits. This is the adult on a passionfruit (where you normally find them), and the nymph is even more colourful:

[image]

Comment: +1 and [confirmed here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0nfmTHu4P2oC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=lahare+Aanp&source=bl&ots=yrHN05oNxH&sig=BM8cwgk4UphCmlBoeYq1_i2DBmg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAxO6X-OXVAhVsB8AKHS5dAcMQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=lahare%20Aanp&f=false) (if links to Google books actually persist).

Comment: @AlanBoyd good investigative skills! I actually identified the fruit straight away because I'm from South America, where *Passiflora* is native.

Comment: [The Christian connections with the name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passion_flower?wprov=sfti1) are much more elaborate.

Comment: Indeed! I added that link to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Do you know any (free) database for species names in various languages?

Comment: In South Africa it's more commonly referred to as Grenadilla

Comment: @pufferfish: Thank you! "Granadilla" is the word I've been looking for for a few years now. I forgot what we called it back in ZA.

Comment: The flaps on the hind legs of the insect are quite intriguing.