# Can somebody identify this insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It has transparent wings which covers the body like an armor. It has shining red orange colour.

[image]

I found it in the western ghats of kerala.

Comment: Now, that's an interesting insect. But, we post pictures here on the insect, and it's likely a better photo is needed (but not absolute.)

Answer (score 8):

This is a **tortoise beetle**, a coleopteran from the Family [Cassidinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassidinae).

According to the [Queensland Museum](http://www.qm.qld.gov.au/Find+out+about/Behind+the+Scenes/Museum+Experts/Biodiversity/Tortoise+Beetles#.We8-gluCxdg):

> tortoise beetles are quite distinctive because they’re actually quite flattened and their wing covers are expanded around the edges. So the wing covers are the hard forewings that protect the hind wings in beetles and because they’re spread out at the sides, they look somewhat like a turtle or a tortoise. So that’s how they get their common name.

There are many beautiful specimens, like these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Your photo is not exactly the best one, but based only on it I'd say that your specimen is a [golden tortoise beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspidimorpha_sanctaecrucis) (*Aspidimorpha sanctaecrucis*):

[image]

Here is another image of it, even more similar to your specimen:

[image]

Comment: That's my favorite insect from this day!

Comment: Mine is the passion fruit bug: https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/65070/24284